# Laravel 5.4: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found error

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5

I am following the Laracast's API tutorial and trying to create an `ApiController` that all the other controllers extend. `ApiController` is responsible for response handling.

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    protected $statusCode;

    public function getStatusCode()
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function setStatusCode($statusCode)
    {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
    }

    public function respondNotFound($message = 'Not Found!')
    {
        return Reponse::json([

            'error' => [
                'message' => $message,
                'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
            ]

        ]);
    }
}
```

And i also have a `ReportController` that extends `ApiController`.

```
class ReportController extends ApiController
{
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $report = Report::find($id);

        if (! $report ) {
            $this->respondNotFound(Report does not exist.');
        }

        return Response::json([
            'data'=> $this->ReportTransformer->transform($report)
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

When i try to call `respondNotFound` method from `ReportController` i get

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found error

eventhough i add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;`to parent or child class i get the error. How can i fix this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `use Response;` instead. Or the `response()` helper - `return response()->json(...);`.

Comment: Seems the namespace you are using to import the class `Response` is not correct. use the correct one.

Comment: Use statements are per file, you still have to include them in child classes even if they are included in the parent. Either add the facade use statement in the child class or use `\Response`

Answer (score 48):

Since it's a facade, add this:

```
use Response;
```

Or use full namespace:

```
return \Response::json(...);
```

Or just use helper:

```
return response()->json(...);
```

Comment: Where to put use statement ?

Comment: At the top of your file. After the `namespace` declaration.

Comment: @Tartar At the top of the file that's using the `Response`, after the `<?php` and `namespace` lines. You'll likely see one or more `use` statements there already.

Comment: Yeah but i mean to parent or child or both ?

Comment: @Tartar anywhere it is used. Use statement are per file, they do not extend to child classes unless they are all defined in the same file.

Comment: I put it both to parent and child classes. Still getting the same error.

Comment: It's impossible for the `return \Response...` option to throw the error you describe. If that approach still results in this error, **you've missed one.** Or you're editing the wrong files, or you've got a cache issue.

Comment: @ceejayoz when i put \Response, it is not giving the expected response, same goes for helper function. There is no error but they return an empty array.

Comment: That's a **totally** different issue, and it's really frustrating that you'd say "None of these solutions above work, tried them all" without noting that they **did** work to resolve the error message you described.