# Getting 500 error code while fetching data from DB using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-6

I am getting a 500 error code while fetching data from the database using Ajax in Laravel with the following function:

```php
public function search(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $query = $request->get('query');
        $data = Constant_model::get_icons('fontawesomeicons', 'id', 'DESC', 20, $query);
    }

    return response($data->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

get_icons function is:

```php
public static function get_icons($table, $order_column, $order_type, $limit, $search = '')
{
    $result = DB::table($table)
        ->select('*')
        ->orderBy($order_column, $order_type)
        ->where('icon_name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->paginate($limit);

    return $result;
}
```

I am trying to get the data using Ajax with the following Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/icons/search",
    method: "GET",
    data: {
      search: query
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (error) {

        console.log(error);

    },
    success: function(response) {

      alert(response);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please check `storage/logs/` for error. and post specific error.

Comment: [2020-01-24 18:08:32] local.ERROR: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Response' not found at C:\\projects\\bb\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Icons.php:47)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.4: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506361/laravel-5-4-class-app-http-controllers-response-not-found-error)

Comment: Please add all relevant information (especially the error message!) to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

Class `App\Http\Controllers\Response`.  You forgot to `use Response` in above your code.
Put that in:

```
use Response;
```

Or just use a helper, if you don't want to import it:

```
 return response()->json(...);
```

Now in your case, you must return it, like this:

```
return response()->json($data->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_OK);
```